# Include php preg_replace in string

Tags: php

I am trying to include a php function within a string but my syntax is wrong. Could anyone help please?

```
$string = "<div id=\"apostnav\"><span class=\"calcir b-" . $string=get_field('br_category');
$string=preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $string);
echo strtolower($string) . "></span></div>";
```

Comment: You can't define a new variable inside another variable definition.

Comment: @user2342558 although meaningless (the value of `$string` is immediately overwritten) that is perfectly valid PHP. https://3v4l.org/tuZTh

Comment: @Nick Ahh, I just learned something interesting :) thanks

Comment: @user2342558 I do think your answer is actually what OP wants, it's just that statement which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string=get_field('br_category');
$string=preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $string);

$string = "<div id=\"apostnav\"><span class=\"calcir b-" . strtolower($string) . "\"></span></div>";
```

I moved up two lines of code andn removed an `echo` from the last one.

Here the code with few optimizations:

```
$string = get_field('br_category');
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", '', $string);
$stringLower = strtolower($string);

$string = "<div id='apostnav'><span class='calcir b-$stringLower'></span></div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [printf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) too in order to print your html string with the variable:

```
printf('<div id="apostnav"><span class="calcir b-%s"></span></div>', strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', get_field('br_category'))));
```